# Express and Jade, passing in variables

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, express, captcha, recaptcha

I'm trying to install this captcha plugin and this is what I have so far (straight from their code, just kind of tweaked up to my style)

Here is captcha and steps I'm following: `https://github.com/mirhampt/node-recaptcha`

In my `router.js` file:

`app.get('/account/verification/:token/', require('./views/account/verification/index').verifyHuman);`

In my `/views/account/verification/index.js` file:

```
exports.verifyHuman = function(req, res, next){
  var Recaptcha = require('recaptcha').Recaptcha;
  var recaptchaKeys = req.app.config.recaptchaKeys;
  var recaptcha = new Recaptcha(recaptchaKeys.publicKey, recaptchaKeys.privateKey);

  console.log(recaptcha.toHTML()); //this returns a script tag with an iframe and stuff in it

  res.render('account/verification/captcha', {
      layout: false,
      locals: {
          recaptcha_form: recaptcha.toHTML()
      }
  });
};
```

and then my `/views/account/verification/captcha.jade` file:

```
      div#captcha
  script(type='text/template', id='tmpl-captcha-verification')
    form#captcha-verification
      #{recaptcha_form}

      button.btn.btn-primary.btn-captcha-verification(type='button') Check Captcha
```

I can't get it do display the captcha script. It comes up as undefined but in a strange way. This is what appears in my console:

```
<script type="text/template" id="tmpl-captcha-verification"><form id="captcha-verification"><undefined></undefined><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-captcha-verification">Check Captcha</button></form></script>
```

I can even try and do `#{layout}`, and I get this in the console:

```
<script type="text/template" id="tmpl-captcha-verification"><form id="captcha-verification"><false></false><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-captcha-verification">Check Captcha</button></form></script>
```

It's like jade is trying to format it, but one of the main issues is that it's undefined, when the variable in my `/views/account/verification/index.js` file that I `console.log` isn't.

Also, note that if I do `!= recaptcha_form`, it just shows the form in the html as it would if this `!= recaptcha_form` code wasn't even there.

I've searched around other questions for this answer and am still pretty confused. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Why are yo trying to put HTML tags inside your script element ? There should not be anything inside your script tag.

Comment: @WaldoJeffers I'm using backbone js and that's a pretty common thing to do

Comment: my bad, I'm not used to Backbone.
Change `{layout: false,locals: { recaptcha_form: recaptcha.toHTML() } }` to `{ layout: false, recaptcha_form: recaptcha.toHTML()}`

Comment: @WaldoJeffers you get a cookie, but the recaptcha_form code has a script tag in it which happens to be closing my <script type="text/template"> tag early when the recaptcha_form code gets to the </script> tag. If you have any idea how to fix this, I'll bake you a cake :p

Comment: Could you edit your post to show exactly what happens and where it's prematurely closed ?

Also, I suggest you retry the unescaped syntax : `form#captcha-verification != recaptcha_form`
If that doesn't work, it's because you are mixing Jade & non-Jade syntax, which Jade doesn't like, though it's supposed to support it.
In that case, go old school : `!= "<script type='text/template' id='tmpl-captcha-verification'><form id='captcha-verification'>" + locals.recaptcha_form + "</form></script>"`

I like cheesecakes by the way.